# Saving and Downloading Image Files with videojs-record Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, videojs-record

I'm currently working with the videojs-record plugin for capturing videos and taking snapshots using a webcam in my web application. I've successfully implemented the recording functionality, and I'm able to save the recorded video files directly and offer them as a download to users.

However, I'm facing a challenge when it comes to saving and downloading the captured image files. With the videojs-record plugin, I can capture snapshots, but I'm unsure how to save these snapshots as image files on the server and provide a download link to users.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js"></video>
<button id="captureImage">Capture Image</button>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const captureImageButton = document.getElementById("captureImage");
  let options = {
    plugins: {
      record: {
        image: true,
        imageOutputFormat: "image/jpeg",
        debug: true
      }
    }
  };
  let player = videojs("my-video", options);

  player.ready(function() {
    player.record().getDevice();
  });

  captureImageButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.record().snapshot();
  });

  player.on("finishRecord", function() {
    // Logic to save the video file works fine
    // Need assistance on saving and downloading the captured image file
  });
});
</script>
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to save the captured image files as individual image files (e.g., JPEG or PNG) on the server and then offer a download link to users. Ideally, I'd like to trigger the download automatically upon capturing the image, but a manual download link would also be acceptable.

Any insights or suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

i tried using `player.record().saveAs({'image': 'file.jpg'});`
because i used it for video (`player.record().saveAs({'image': 'file.jpg'});`) and it worked for that.